# Как вывести информацию при клике на определенный элемент в массиве

Tags: javascript, html, массивы

Такая ситуация:Есть массив элементов с тегом

.

Мне нужно чтобы при клике на определенный элемент li, у меня вывелась инфа которая относится к нажатому элементу.
Иначе у меня получается при нажатии на любой элемент, выводится одна и тажа инфа.

Это как то связано с событием но как задать условия на событие не знаю, понимаю что проблема проста, но в упор не могу разобраться

```html
<ul class="user-info__user-comment-list col-md-3 col-lg-2">
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item">Жанна Блиц</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item">Арина Наумова</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item">Виталий Коробко</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item">Елена Снежная</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item">Юлиана Ветрова</li>
</ul>
```

```js
var blockSevenUserNamesBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.user-info__user-comment-item');


for(var i = 0; i < blockSevenUserNamesBtn.length; i++) {

blockSevenUserNamesBtn[i].addEventListener('click', event=>{
  blockSevenUserNamesBtn.forEach(function (user, index, blockSevenUserNamesBtn ) {
      console.log(user.innerHTML);

 if (user.innerHTML === 'Виталий Коробко')  {

   for (var vitaliiCounter = 0; vitaliiCounter < UserJsonVitalii.length; 
        vitaliiCounter++) {

      blockSevenUserName.innerHTML = UserJsonVitalii[vitaliiCounter].name;
      blockSevenUserAge.innerHTML = UserJsonVitalii[vitaliiCounter].age;
      blockSevenUserComment.innerHTML = UserJsonVitalii[vitaliiCounter].comment;
      blockSevenUserPhoto.src = UserJsonVitalii[vitaliiCounter].photo;

 }
 }
 });
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Дальше обрабатывайте как хотите.
Читайте комментарии в коде.
Несколько уточнений:

- Использовать для userID имя пользователя неправильно, ID должен быть
  уникальным для каждого пользователя. Читайте подробней, например, про uuid/guid.
- В идеале не вы должны ручками прописывать каждый элемент списка, а он должен строится, исходя из имеющихся данных. Получили в JSON 5 юзеров => если нет userID, то назначили userID=> построили список из 5 элементов => каждому элементу списка назначили атрибут userID соответствующий ID пользователя.

```js
//Предположим, уже извлекли data со всеми юзерами из JSON и имеем массив такого плана.
let data = [{
        "name": "Жанна Блиц",
        "age": 29,
        "comment": "Cupidatat enim occaecat tempor laborum esse eu quis aliquip pariatur ex."
    },
    {
        "name": "Арина Наумова",
        "age": 39,
        "comment": "Labore mollit cupidatat duis occaecat deserunt non ea ipsum mollit laborum enim cupidatat."
    },
    {
        "name": "Виталий Коробко",
        "age": 32,
        "comment": "Esse qui velit pariatur ex dolor id adipisicing tempor aliquip duis laborum."
    },
    {
        "name": "Елена Снежная",
        "age": 31,
        "comment": "Non ullamco ipsum do reprehenderit veniam dolor ex fugiat Lorem fugiat proident incididunt ad laborum."
    },
    {
        "name": "Юлиана Ветрова",
        "age": 35,
        "comment": "Ut non culpa ea elit et ullamco voluptate nisi."
    }
]
// правильней в такой ситуации станачала строить список с именами, а уже потом по клику раскрывать данные.
// Но в данном случае поступим, как вы изначально запланировали.

/* Создадим на основе массива новый объект такой структуры 
{
    ID: {User Data}
}
    Конкретно в вашем случае ID будет "Имя и фамилия пользователя"
*/

//в данном объекте у нас будут храниться все пользователи с их данными.
let users = {};

data.forEach(({name, age, comment}) => { //Если что, это называется деструктуризация
    users[`${name}`] = {name, age, comment};
})
/*Мы это делаем для удобства обращения с данными. 
Теперь мы можем получать информацию о конкретном пользователе не перебором
массива, а обращаясь к конкретному объекту users по ID пользователя, 
в данном случае это имя пользователя.
*/


let comments = document.querySelector(".user-info__user-comment-list")
comments.onclick = (event) => {
    //инфа выводится
    if (event.target.classList.contains("user-info__user-comment-item")) {
        //в идеале, userID должен быть уникальным у каждого юзера и должен указываться в prop`ах (не путать с ID элемента). 
        //В текущем варианте повторный клик на элемент не будет давать каких-либо результатов.
        {
        let userID = event.target.textContent;
        //Проверяем наличие юзера
        if (users[`${userID}`]) {
            //выдергиваем нужного юзера, также используем деструктуризацию
            let {name, age, comment} = users[`${userID}`];

            //заполняем данные
            event.target.textContent = `${name}, возраст: ${age}, коментарий: ${comment}`;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="user-info__user-comment-list col-md-3 col-lg-2">
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item" userID="уникальный ID">Жанна Блиц</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item" userID="уникальный ID">Арина Наумова</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item" userID="уникальный ID">Виталий Коробко</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item" userID="уникальный ID">Елена Снежная</li>
   <li class="user-info__user-comment-item" userID="уникальный ID">Юлиана Ветрова</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, json общий, но предварительно разбиваю

Comment: @Артур дополнил, читайте коменты.

Comment: Огромная благодарность за такое подробное разъяснение!

Смотрю код, да все понятно, что из чего следует. Но когда садишься сам писать, за что взяться, откуда начать, это с ума сводит, вот эта вот последовательность, раздробление шагов, реализация способом, наверное это уже с опытом приходит. Когда появилась задача и уже понимаешь какие шаги нужно сделать и каким способом.

Еще раз. Спасибо за такое объяснение.